# R: performence, memory use. Writing a text file or keeping all the information in R objects?

Tags: performance, r, memory-management

Through iteration I construct a very big matrix and in order to speed up these iterations I split this matrix into chunks which I put in a list.

Would I have better to save my chunks of matrix into a text file and append the new chunk on this same text file instead of keeping them all in a list. Does it change anything in terms of memory use and performence (time to run the simulation) ?

second question: Is there a way to know the memory size of an R object (without having to save it into a .Rdata file)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I'd say, if you can keep everything in RAM, do it that way, it will be faster. If you are running out of memory, you can save your objects into an .Rdata file (with `save`), which is faster than a text file, and then `load` them later when you need them.

Comment: @Juba Thanks for your answer. So is there a way to know the memory size of a given R objects (without having to save it into a .Rdata file) ?

Comment: You can use the `object.size()` function.

Comment: Why not try and find it out?

Comment: If you're saving single objects one at a time I would use `saveRDS()` in preference to `save()`. `save()` from the documentation is used to "save and restore one or more named objects into an environment". Also for speed purposes, consider what compression you want to use. `save()` and `saveRDS()` have options for compressing or not that can speed things up. I think (but haven't tested anything) that it might be faster to save/load objects without compression. But then you have the disadvantage of having larger files if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retain the matrix in RAM if possible. Else you can also look into [bigmemory package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html).

And the latest version of R has better support for large vectors. It will helpful if you have 64-bit machine with large amounts of RAM.

Note:Since we are talking about performance, it is a good practice to pre-allocate the matrix (instead of frequent use of rbind / cbind)

Comment: +1 for preallocation! Just a remark though, if the matrices are only the results, i.e. not needed for further analysis, it does not really matter if you dump the content during the analysis, or after it. This is ofcourse assuming that RAM is not a problem, or else dumping it is favorable. Dumping the files during analysis could even speed things up if you dump the file during CPU intensive periods.